# validation for element generated by ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I want to show validation errors on a form inside which its generating some elements using ng-repeat. I am not sure why its not working correctly.

```
<form id="myForm" name="myForm">
    <div ng-repeat="i in items">
        <input type="text" name="myElem.inner[$index].result" ng-model="item.result" />
        <label ng-show="myForm.myElem.inner[$index].result.$error.required">Error...</label>
    </div>
</form>
```

I have also tried to generate the json for {{myForm.myElem.inner[$index] | json}} but its returning empty. How to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

In a `ng-repeat` form validation need to be done differently. The `name` property should be string it cannot be a expression nor can it take an interpolation. 
You would have to do nested forms in case of `ng-repeat`. Since nested forms are not allowed in html you need to use `ng-form` directive. The code then would look like

```
<form id="myForm" name="myForm">
    <div ng-repeat="item in items">
        <ng-form name="itemForm">
            <input type="text" name="name" ng-model="item.result" />
            <label ng-show="itemForm.name.$error.required">Error...</label>
        </ng-form>
    </div>
</form>
```

See ngForm documentation too https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.15/docs/api/ng/directive/ngForm.

Comment: I cannot use simple name="name" I must have to use complex one like myElem.inner[0].result etc

Comment: actually you can. The name property would now be added to ng-repeat  scope i think so there would be no conflict. For form name should be fixed model can change.